# mov [rcx], rbx is moved to the start or end of the address from rcx?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86-64, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I would like to ask you a question about registers. I am totally a beginner in this so forgive me if question is trivial.

I would like to know if I write in code:

```
mov rcx, DigitSpace
mov rbx, 10
mov [rcx], rbx
```

A value of rbx will be added at the beginning of [rcx] address register or at the end of it?

I have tried to read about registers but did not find the answer....

Comment: That's an 8-byte store to memory, like C `memcpy(&DigitSpace, &local_var, 8)`.  Where RBX is a uint64_t holding the value `10`.  (Registers don't have addresses, but C memcpy only works by reference; C isn't assembly language).  The address of a qword memory location is the address of its lowest-address byte.  Are you asking about which byte will be non-zero if you do that?  x86 is little-endian, so it'll be the low byte, like if you'd done `mov [rcx], bl` and stored zeros at the next 7 addresses.

Comment: "*like C `memcpy(...)`*" - Except that `mov rcx, DigitSpace` is storing the *value* of `DigitSpace` into `rcx` rather than its *address*. So, it doesn't make sense to use `[rcx]` afterwards, unless `DigitSpace` is a pointer rather than a character/integer. Otherwise, you would need `lea rcx, DigitSpace` instead to store the address.

Comment: Thank you very much gentelmens, now I now what it's all about. Everything will be much easier. I am following tutorial of making subroutine that divides two integers. Have a nice evening. :)